How can I fix my civicrm database table schema?
Once upon a time, if you thought your database schema was no longer matching what CiviCRM expected, it was recommended that you create a new civicrm install with your current version, dump it and your production site without data, and compare.
Of course, that's a bit of a bear, especially because sometimes the order of the fields might be different.
Now that we have a new way of defining the schema, what's the best way of reviewing my database for e.g. missing db upgrade steps? And fixing it! Anybody got some useful code and/or processes?
FWIW, this civicrm install was created more than 10 years ago.

I'd say dump is still the best way.

When is ChatGPT going to solve this problem? What's the point of AI if it doesn't solve my problems?

Hehe. I don't think solving our problems was ever the purpose. But I'd be curious what it says about this problem.

I had this exact problem with an 11 year old install, missing FK constraints, and dumping it had some benefits of getting rid of junk that an "AI driven" rebuild would have missed.

Alternatively to dump-without-data-and-compare, I could dump the new install without data, and dump production without the schema (--no-create-info) and then load up the aspirational schema and then the production data, fingers crossed.
